# system("command") produces an error; but it works when invoked directly from Bash prompt

Tags: c++, linux, bash

I am trying to run the following bash command from my C++ program:

```
diff <(cat /etc/passwd) <(ls -l /etc)
```

with the following C++ statement:

```
system("diff <(cat /etc/passwd) <(ls -l /etc)");
```

The command works fine when running it directly from the Linux shell but when running it from my program, I get:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

That's referring to the `(`

I have tried escaping the `(` with a `\`, but that creates more issues:

```
system("diff <\\(cat /etc/passwd\\) <\\(ls -l /etc\\)");

sh: 1: cannot open (cat: No such file
```

All I want is to run the following from my C++ program:

```
diff <(cat /etc/passwd) <(ls -l /etc)
```

I can create a file and run it, but I leave that as a last option.

Comment: Try to call bash directly.

Comment: `<()` process-substitution is a `bash` feature. It cannot run in `POSIX` sh shell.

Comment: @marko `system("bash -c \"diff <(cat /etc/passwd) <(ls -l /etc)\"")`

Comment: Put your command in a bash script and call the script.

Comment: For this specific case you don't actually need process substitution, you could use a pipeline which sh does handle: `ls -l /etc | diff /etc/passwd -`

Comment: `<(cat /etc/passwd)` can be replaced with `/etc/passwd`, man `cat file` commands are redundant.

Comment: Why are you comparing the content of `/etc` with `/etc/passwd`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As mentioned `system()` creates a new standard shell `sh` and executes the commands. Since `<()` is a bash specific feature it can't be interpreted by `sh`.

You can circumvent this by calling `bash` explicitly and use the `-c` option:

```
system("bash -c \"diff <(cat /etc/passwd) <(ls -l /etc)\"");
```

or using a raw string literal:

```
system(R"cmd(bash -c "diff <(cat /etc/passwd) <(ls -l /etc)")cmd");
```

---

Here's the relevant part of the [`system(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) call manual page:

> The `system()` library function uses `fork(2)` to create a child process
>    that executes the shell command specified in command using `execl(3)`
>    as follows:
>
> ```
>  execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) 0);
> ```
>
> `system()` returns after the command has been completed.

Comment: Or, as the man page indirectly suggests, you can call `execl("/bin/bash", "bash",  ...` yourself.

Comment: @MSalters Sure, including the `fork()` and all that.

Comment: @bolov Done that. Unfortunately the old code highlighter engine doesn't seem to be familiar with raw string literals.

Comment: I'm perplexed myself. For some reason I though system() looked at the SHELL variable.

Comment: @Joshua Same for me, that's why I consulted the documentation ;-)

Comment: Since when does C++ have "raw string literals", and how on earth is the tokenizer supposed to know where that one ends???

Comment: @zwol It's part of the [current standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). Waking someone who slept under a rock? ;-)

Comment: @user0042 OK, I see how that works now, but I don't think you should recommend anyone use it (or any other shiny new C++ feature) for at least 10 years after standardization; that's how long it takes for them to become sufficiently widespread.  Notice how the syntax highlighter doesn't grok it?

Comment: @zwol _"shiny new"_ seriously?? The markup syntax highlighter is old BTW, and outdates with many newer features.

Comment: @user0042 Yes seriously.  Ten years is optimistic; some features of the 1999 C standard are _still_ not universally available.  This particular feature, I would expect commercial compiler developers won't bother implementing until someone specifically pays for it.

Answer (score 7):

The `system(3)` call invokes `/bin/sh` to process the command. If you want specifically use `bash` features, you need to insert `bash -c` in front of the command string, which will run `bash` and tell it to process the remainder of the string.

```
system("bash -c \"diff <(cat /etc/passwd) <(ls -l /etc)\"");
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that although I did find the `sh:` part somewhat weird because I was starting from `bash` so I expected the process to run from a `bash` shell but I didn't know about the `sh` shell not accepting process-substitution.

Comment: In the case of `system`, it only invokes `/bin/sh` because that is the only shell guaranteed to be available on all systems (`bash` is nearly always these days, but is technically considered 'optional' extra).

If you want to use the same shell as you were invoked from, look into `fork`/`exec` and variants, and query the `SHELL` environment variable.

Comment: This won't work without the internal quotation seen in the accepted answer.